# Replacing values of categorical Variable in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Categorical Variable : Gender **|**
dtype: Object **|**
Values: Male, male, m, M, Female, female, f, F **|**

I want to replace all values to 'Male' & 'Female' accoridingly.  Replace is not working, showing that 'Male' and 'Female' does not exist. I can replace them by 1 & 0 but I don't want to make it an ordinal variable

**This is my code:-**

```
bck = pd.read_csv('BCK.csv')
bck['Gender'].value_counts()
bck.Gender.dtype
bck['Gender'] = bck['Gender'].astype('str')
bck.Gender.dtype
bck.Gender.replace(to_replace=dict(m = Male, f = Female, male =  Male,     female =  Female, M = Male, F  = Female), inplace=True)
```

This is not working and displaying, " Male does not exist".

Comment: `Replace is not working, showing that 'Male' and 'Female' does not exist.` Please supply a **[mcve]** demonstrating this behaviour. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) if you need help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Gender'].str[0].str.upper().map({'M':'Male', 'F':'Female'})
```

#### Explanation

This chains two `Series.str` accessor methods and `Series.map` to:

1. Return the first character of each `Gender` value by indexing at `[0]`
   eg. `'male'[0] = m` and `'Female'[0] = 'F'`
2. `str.upper()` to upper case all of these values
3. Finally, `.map` to map 'M' to 'Male' and 'F' to 'Female'

Comment: Thanks Chris, It woked!

Comment: Can you please explain why this worked, "bck['Gender'].str[0].str.upper().map({'M':'Male', 'F':'Female', 'male': 'Male', 'female': 'Female'}) and this did not, bck['Gender'].map({'M':'Male', 'F':'Female', 'male': 'Male', 'female': 'Female'})

Comment: no problem @DeepakLunawat, updated my answer. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

you're dictionary is not correct. You also have them as variables which should be saying `name 'Male' is not defined`, not that they don't exist. They need to be strings.

Try:

```
bck.Gender.replace({'m':'Male', 'f':'Female', 'male':'Male','female':'Female', 'M':'Male', 'F':'Female'}), inplace=True)
```

or can use `.map` function:

```
x = {'m':'Male', 'f':'Female', 'male':'Male','female':'Female', 'M':'Male', 'F':'Female'}

bck['Gender'] = bck['Gender'].map(x)
```